# Keyboard not showing

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard, hide, show

I used this code to prevent keyboard from hiding (on iPad):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)keyboard {
    return NO;
}
```

It works, but when I back to previous window in storyboard, and then again enter to window with this code, keyboard is not showing at all.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

add `[yourTextField becomeFirstResponder];`
to your viewDidAppear.

Comment: @user2641529: it's impossible for others to know this details (thus harder to answer) unless you add them to your post. Check (with `NSLog`) is your `viewDidAppear` is called when coming back from previous view